# Move custom options into default.phtml

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options

I want to list the options box move from view.phtml to default.phtml. Tried to copy and paste

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

into default.phtml. But this does not help to show the options on frontend :(

Comment: This is not a full answer, but 'getChildChildHtml' refers to the child nodes in layout xml files. So you'll need to replicate those nodes in your checkout.xml to get started, but I believe there are many more steps needed to actually make them functional.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is set-up these child blocks against the correct block that you want them to show.

If by default.phtml you mean `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml` then the blocks you are looking for are as follows:

1. name="product.info.simple" - using the handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple`
2. name="product.info.configurable" - using the handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable`
3. name="product.info.virtual" - using the handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual`

First thing that you need to do is unset the current positioning of the container1 and container2 blocks.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.container1</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.container2</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now that we have done this we can consider moving these items and to do so we can simply insert these blocks in the correct handle.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <reference name="product.info.simple">
        <action method="insert"><child>product.info.container1</child></action>
        <action method="insert"><child>product.info.container2</child></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="product.info.configurable">
        <action method="insert"><child>product.info.container1</child></action>
        <action method="insert"><child>product.info.container2</child></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
<PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>
    <reference name="product.info.virtual">
        <action method="insert"><child>product.info.container1</child></action>
        <action method="insert"><child>product.info.container2</child></action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual>
```